# How to fix unresolved import error in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning to use Django but I ran into an error. `manage.py` can no longer import `excecute_from_command_line` from `django.core.management` That is, in manage.py file the following line of code isn't working, it's underlined with yellow line in vscode.

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

I have tried to fix it myself but ain't able to do that. I want someone to help me with the possible cause of this issue.

Comment: You might be using a virtual environment, make sure you are in the venv before exceuting any code. Also configure your venv settings in vscode so that it won't show false errors.

Comment: Maybe because it is spelled differently.

Comment: Yeah,  @Abdul, I'm in the right virtualenv

Comment: @Klaus, the spellings are correct in the text editor, it's the one provided by Django when I created the project. I didn't mess with the content of the file. Everything was working correctly the previous day,  only for me to open the project the following day and saw the error.

Comment: Dude, it's `execute` without `c` after the `x`.

Comment: Thanks for pinpointing that error. That was a mistake on my part while typing it here, everything is spelled correctly in the original work. Still, the issue is there

Comment: `pip freeze` does the output of this command show django in it?

Comment: @Abdul, yes it has Django in it. I can't even run `python manage.py` anymore. If I run it, it tells me `main` is not defined. It's pointing to the `main()` in manage.py file

Answer (score 0):

If you use vscode go to view then click the command pallete search for (python: select interpreter) then (enter the interpreter path) then (find) and go to your project virtual environment folder then select the python3 application file, that's it.

Comment: its not work on me, can you help me fix it? i have the same problem